# Custom Timestamp for files when using Wise for windows installer

Tags: windows-installer, wise

if I am making a MSI package with say 10 files, then can I give all the files a specific timestamp say, 10th august 2016, while creating the MSI package using wise for windows installer version 5.0 or would I need some other tool?

Answer (score 1):

Windows Installer uses timestamps on data files during updates to decide if a data file needs to be updated:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370531(v=vs.85).aspx

and the Creation and Modify dates get set at install time. So modifying dates before install doesn't make any difference because Windows Installer sets the Creation and Modify dates the same to detect any change after they've been installed. Changing them after the install will potentially break the update detection mechanism. If they are binaries then versions are used to identify the particular build.

See also:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2013/05/23/updating-the-last-modified-time-to-prevent-windows-installer-from-updating-an-unversioned-file/

where he deliberately changes dates after install to prevent overwrite. In other words, as I said, if you change dates after install you are altering patch/upgrade overwrite rules.

Comment: I didn't encounter such a scenario as you describe as my input files to MSI and Output files from MSI to Program Files folder has always had the same timestamp. I assume then that this behavior is controlled through some property then. Anyways I would have liked to change the timestamps for the input files through MSI packaging steps without using tools like Renamer etc

Comment: Depends what you mean by "timestamp" because there are several. Windows Installer sets the Creation time to be the same as the Modify time, and one of them will not change, so perhaps that's the one you're looking at. It's not an optional feature or controlled by a property. Just look at the Create and Modify timestamps of the input file, then install your setup and check them. The entire "don't overwrite modified files" depends on this, if it didn't do this it would be a catastrophe!